# reading variable from xml file in flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, model, arraylist

I'm trying to read the address of a flv file from an xml file and then put it in the "source" property of a videodisplay tag . 
here's my code :

```
//in decleration tags
<fx:Model id="myModel" source="myXML.xml"/>
<s:ArrayList id="myArrList" source="{myModel.main}"/>

//in the main code
<mx:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay" source="{myArrList.getItemAt(0)}" />
```

and the xml file is:

```
<main>
<myFile>"g:\myflv.flv"</myFile>
</main>
```

anyone knows what's wrong?
tnx

Comment: 1. No need to add double quotes around the path of the video in the xml
 2. Is <main> the root tag of your xml?

Comment: trace myArrList.getItemAt(0) to see.

Comment: @Florian : yes main is the root tag

Answer (score 0):

For now, this will work :

```
//in decleration tags
<fx:Model id="myModel" source="myXML.xml"/>

//in the main code
<mx:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay" source="{myModel.mainFile as String}" />
```

However, if you add more  tags in your XML, it will not work anymore.
You Model instance is actually an ObjectProxy instance.
If there is one  tag, the Flex framework will create an ObjectProxy with a myFile property that is a String. If there are more than one tag, the myFile property will be an Array.

So, If you really want to use an ArrayList instance, you won't have any other choice than doing something similar to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               applicationComplete="application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)"
               >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                if (myModel.myFile is Array)
                    myArrList = new ArrayList(myModel.myFile)
                else
                    myArrList = new ArrayList([myModel.myFile]);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Model id="myModel" source="myXML.xml" />
        <s:ArrayList id="myArrList" />
    </fx:Declarations>


</s:Application>
```

Also, have you installed the debug version of Flash Player?

Comment: thanks Florian , it worked . but I think the proper way to do this is to use URLRequest and URLLoader classes . there was a document on adobe site about that. and I haven't installed the debug version and that causes problems for me sometimes .

Comment: Yes I highly recommand you to install the flash debug version and see how debugging works in Flash Builder.